# This is regarding Vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $a$ be an object and define $V=\{a\}$.
On $V$, define the addition as $a + a = a$.
Define the scalar multiplication as $ra = a$ for all scalar $r$.
Prove or disprove whether $V$ becomes a vector space under these operations.

Comment: So the space only has one element $a$?

Comment: yes it has only one element.. looks like for a=0 this V becomes a vector space but for other values it will not...

Answer (score 1):

Take any field $F$, and consider the trivial vector space $\{ 0 \}$ over $F$. Now compare this to your vector space $V$.

Comment: thanks for the answer sir..yeah i know that for a=0 this V becomes a vector space.. but sir only a=0 this becomes a vector space... otherwise not... doesn't it require to be for any value of a ,V becomes a vector space???

Comment: @RandunuWaitforItPalihakkara when I said *compare*, I mean, the vector spaces $\{ 0 \}$ and $V$ are isomorphic as vector spaces. So $a$ is just another name for $0$.

Comment: yes its true....

Comment: @RandunuWaitforItPalihakkara, alternatively, note that in a vector space each element $a$ has an opposite $-a$ such that $a + (-a) = 0$. So from $a + a = a$ you get $a = a + 0 = a + a + (-a) = a + (-a) = 0$.

Comment: @ChampR A vector space is required to have a "zero vector". But being the "zero vector" does not necessarily have anything to do with the number zero or the symbol $0$. A vector $x$ fills the role of the zero vector if $x+y=y$ for all $y$ in the space. What symbol is attached to $x$ doesn't matter.

Comment: For example, let $X=(0,\infty)$. Define $r\oplus s=rs$ for $r,s\in X$. Define $t\otimes x=x^t$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in X$. Then $(X,\mathbb{R},\oplus,\otimes)$ is a vector space and the zero vector is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

one property ofa  vector space(as V) is for every $a\in V $then $-a \in V$ so $a-a=0$ must be in $V$ and V is singletone ({a}) then a=0

Comment: This doesn't address the question (you cannot apply properties of vector spaces without first assuming that $V$ is a vector space; that's unproductive unless you intend to disprove that $V$ is a vector space). It is also needlessly complex: a basic property of vector spaces is that they contain a $0$ element, and $V$ contains only one element $a$, forcing $a$ to be that $0$ element.